# Docker file in host machine not available in container using bind volume

Tags: docker

I am facing an issue where after runnig the container and using bind mount to mount the directory on host to container I am not able to see new files created in host machine inside container.Below is my project structure.

[image]

The python code creates a file inside the container which should be available inside the host machine too however this does happen when I start the container with below command. However updates to python code and html is available inside the container.

```
sudo docker container run -p 5000:5000  --name flaskapp --volume feedback1:/app/feedback/ --volume /home/deepak/PycharmProjects/NewDockerProject/sampleapp:/app  flask_image
```

However after starting the container using below command, everything seems to work fine. I can see all the files from container to host and vice versa(new created , edited).I git this command from docker in the month of lunches book.

```
sudo docker container run --mount type=bind,source=/home/deepak/PycharmProjects/NewDockerProject/sampleapp,target=/app -p 5000:5000 --name flaskapp
```

Below is the content of my dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .


CMD ["python","main.py"]
```

Could someone please help me  in figuring out the difference between the two commands ? I am using ubuntu. Thank you

Comment: Have you created a volume called `feedback1` using `docker volume create --name feedback1` ?

Comment: yes I have created

Answer (score 0):

In my case i got working volumes using following docker run args (but i am running without ***--mount type=bind***):

```
docker run  -it ... -v mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql -v storage:/usr/shared/app_storage
```

where:

- mysql_data is a **volume name**
- /var/lib/mysql path **inside** container machine

you could list volumes as:

```
docker volume ls
```

and inspect them to see where it points on your system (usually /var/lib/docker/volumes/{volume_nanme}/_data):

```
docker volume inspect mysql_data
```

to create volume use following command:

```
docker volume create {volume_name}
```